# Use of Django and GeoDjango simultaneously

Tags: django, django-models, geodjango, django-2.2

I've a doubt about the use of GeoDjango with Django.
I've got two apps in my project: `Blog` and `Map`. These two apps are in relation with a third app `Kernel`. Inside Kernel there are some models useful for Blog and Map and one of them is the *TimeManager*.

`TimeManager` is a simple model that "**manages the time**":

```
from django.db import models

class TimeManager(models.Model):
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'Published at',
        default=timezone.now,
        )
    updating_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'Updated at',
        auto_now=True,
        )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=False,
        auto_now_add=True,
        )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Into Blog there is a model Post:

```
from django.db import models

from kernel.models import TimeManager

class Post(TimeManager):
    title=
    slug=
    descrtiption=
    .
    .
```

Into Map there is a model MyMap:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

from kernel.models import TimeManager

class MyMap(TimeManager):
    geom = models.PointField()
    title = 
    .
    .
```

Now, my doubt is this: Is it correct to use TimeManager both for geometric models and not geometric models? I know that GeoDjango inherit from Django models but I don't know if my approach is correct.

Comment: I'd say it's fine to do that and I don't see any cons. However, I'd like to hear other opinions too in case I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no problem at all. GeoDjango is very well integrated into the Django project itself, so there is no reason for conflict here. GeoDjango is part of the contrib package. [The Django docs on the contrib package:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/#contrib-packages)

> Django aims to follow Python’s “batteries included” philosophy. It
>   ships with a variety of extra, optional tools that solve common
>   Web-development problems.
>
> This code lives in **django/contrib** in the Django distribution.

This means you can assume that any additional Django functionality included in django.contrib plays well with the rest of Django.

Just make sure you document which apps use GeoDjango, and how you configure the geospatial libraries on your system, in case you want to turn your apps into reusable libraries and you should be good.

As long Kernel is some kind of base app, this kind of use case is a pretty [DRY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58577805/use-of-django-and-geodjango-simultaneously) way of creating objects that have some kind of date and time management.